# Run typemock unit testing on Visual Studio without typemock extension tools installed

Tags: typemock

I need run Typemock unit tests on Visual Studio without the typemock extension installed.
Of course, I have a license for typemock. Can I achieve the functionality of 'Integrate with Other Runners' without installing extension tools?